# Compilation error "Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener"

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-web

I am using spring-4.0.1.RELEASE, spring-oauth-security-2.0.7.RELEASE.

I already cleaned, installed, compiled the project but did not made any difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>School Days</display-name>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/rest-dispatcher-servlet-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Dispatcher Servlet (Front Controller / Servlet Context) only presentation layer is defined here. -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Although everything looks fine but code is not compiling with exception :

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1' while setting constructor argument with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1' while setting constructor argument with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 47 more
```

Also, the security configuration file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
    <http 
        pattern="/oauth/token" 
        create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
            <anonymous enabled="false" />
            <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
            <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
            <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
            <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>



    <!-- Protected resources -->
    <http 
        pattern="/questionsAndAnaswers/**"
        create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/questionsAndAnaswers/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="dstest" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>



    <!-- Authentication in config file -->
    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>



    <!-- Token Store -->
    <!-- <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" /> -->

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        <!-- VIV -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>



    <!-- Token management -->
    <oauth:authorization-server 
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" 
        token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
            <oauth:authorization-code />
            <oauth:implicit />
            <oauth:refresh-token />
            <oauth:client-credentials />
            <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server 
        id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="dstest" 
        token-services-ref="tokenServices" />


    <!-- Client Definition -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

        <oauth:client 
            client-id="my-trusted-client"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
            authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" 
            redirect-uri="/web"
            scope="read,write,trust" 
            access-token-validity="300"
            refresh-token-validity="600" />

    </oauth:client-details-service>


    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>
    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

</beans>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Post your security configuration. Also your setup is flawed because you are loading all your beans twice. Both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` load the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` which leads to loading and initializing all the beans in that file twice. Which can lead to unexpected results, not to mention to you occupy unnecessary server resources.

Comment: got it, let me update the question with security configuration file. and resolve the twice bean loading thing.